# JavaFX: Remove special day while itarating over it

Tags: java, date, javafx

I know, there are many examples how to remove something from a list while iterating over it, but thats not the point.

I'm trying to automatize a process that I need to document my work (in the end it should be printing into a document something like that **01.01.2019 - Tuesday**). For that I have a UI with two datepicker. After selecting two different dates and comparing them I know how many days are between these dates.

**Now the following problem:**

I'm adding all days between the two dates in a list. After that I'm trying to block some specific days (always the same days: *Monday*, *Saturday* and *Sunday*). These are days that shouldn't be in the list anymore.

I tried things like removing the value out of the list while I'm iterating over it. But it doesn't work the way I expect it to.

**Example:**

I'm selecting the *17.09.2019* as beginning and *24.09.2019* as end. The expected output should be:

> Weekday: TUESDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-18
>   Weekday: WEDNESDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-19
>   Weekday: THURSDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-20
>   Weekday: FRIDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-24
>   Weekday: TUESDAY

but if I run my code the output is:

> Weekday: TUESDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-18
>   Weekday: WEDNESDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-19
>   Weekday: THURSDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-20
>   Weekday: FRIDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-21
>   Weekday: FRIDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-22
>   Weekday: FRIDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-23
>   Weekday: FRIDAY
>   Date: 2019-09-24
>   Weekday: TUESDAY

You can see it. The word Saturday, Sunday and Monday will get removed but it's still in the list.

**Code:**

```
long daysBetween = ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(dateBeginPicker.getValue(), dateEndPicker.getValue());
                int db = Math.toIntExact(daysBetween);

                String day = "";
                List<LocalDate> dateList = new ArrayList<>();
                LocalDate dateAfter = null;

                for (int i = 0; i <= db; i++) {
                    dateAfter = dateBeginPicker.getValue().plusDays(i);
                    dateList.add(dateAfter);
                }

                for (Iterator<LocalDate> iterator = dateList.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                    LocalDate date = iterator.next();

                    if (date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SATURDAY) || date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.SUNDAY) || date.getDayOfWeek().equals(DayOfWeek.MONDAY)) {
                        iterator.remove();
                        dateList.remove(date);
                    }
                    else {
                        day = date.getDayOfWeek().toString();
                    }

                    System.out.println("Date: " + date);
                    System.out.println("Weekday: " + day);
                }
```

What I expecting in the end is, that the every monday, saturday and sunday should removed out of the list, and the output should be correct (as in my example).

Thank you

Comment: Note that a `switch` could make the code a bit easier to read: `switch(date.getDayOfWeek()) { case SATURDAY: case SUNDAY: case MONDAY: /* if body */ break; default: /* else body */}` Furthermore you can use `==` to compare enum constants. Also consider using `removeIf`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have your System.out.println() commands within the for-loop, but outside of the else-block. That's why all of the dates are displayed.

Just move those two lines inside the else-block and you will get the output you want.

Comment: Thank you. But can you explain why monday, saturday and sunday are marked as friday?

Comment: Monday, saturday and Sunday dates are removed in the if-block. You change the day parameter only in the else-part, so they keep the value from the previous loop (Friday)

Answer (score 3):

I am glad that you solved your problem. I would like to add three minor points.

1. You may use a stream if you like.
2. You should not call remove both on the `Iterator` and on the `List`.
3. My explanation of what went wrong in your code.

**1. You may use a stream.** It’s easiest in Java 9 and later:

```
    LocalDate begin = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 17);
    LocalDate end = LocalDate.of(2019, Month.SEPTEMBER, 24);

    final Set<DayOfWeek> blockedDays = EnumSet.of(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY, DayOfWeek.SUNDAY);
    List<LocalDate> dateList = begin.datesUntil(end.plusDays(1))
            .filter(ld -> ! blockedDays.contains(ld.getDayOfWeek()))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

    dateList.forEach(ld -> {
        System.out.println(ld.getDayOfWeek());
        System.out.println(ld);
    });
```

Output is:

> ```
> TUESDAY
> 2019-09-17
> WEDNESDAY
> 2019-09-18
> THURSDAY
> 2019-09-19
> FRIDAY
> 2019-09-20
> TUESDAY
> 2019-09-24
> ```

**2. Don’t call `dateList.remove()`.** Your call to `iterator.remove()` has already removed the date from the list. So your call to `dateList.remove()` does nothing. Which is a luck. If it had found an element to remove, the `Iterator` would have thrown a `ConcurrentModificationException` on the subsequent call to `hasNext()`. You are not allowed to modify a collection while iterating over it except through the iterator, and the result of trying to do it is undefined. So delete that call from your code.

**3. What went wrong in your code?** Your output looks funny. For the blocked days `FRIDAY` is printed along with the date, that is, the day of week and the date don’t match. What happened was: You correctly set `date` to the date from the list. Since the day was a blocked day, you executed the `if` part of the `if` statement, removing the date from the list. You did not execute the `else` part, so `day` is unchanged from the previous iteration, where it was `FRIDAY`. After the `if` statement you unconditionally printed `date`, the blocked date (2019-09-21, 2019-09-22 and 2019-09-23 in turn), and `day` (`FRIDAY` each time).